# How to set all object properties to null in JavaScript?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using Vue and suddenly some of the computed css using [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) is not working.

The way I declare an object is

```
personal_info : {}
```

and in my template, I could just do `personal_info.name` and other more in every v-model of text input.

I have no errors but suddenly the vuetify has a class called `input-group--dirty` that will elevate the label of the text input whenever it's not empty. But suddenly, it's not working. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text and label are overlapping.
The only thing that make it work is to set the property to null which is:

```
personal_info : {
  name: null
}
```

The problem is that I have hundreds of text inputs and I dont want to set everything to null.

Is there a simple way to set all of the object's properties to null instead of coding it 1 by 1?

Comment: You can just set: `personal_info = {}`

Comment: @Saurabh Updated my post

Answer (score 10):

checkout this snippet

```js
var personal_info = {
  name: 'john',
  email: 'john@moto.com',
  phone: 9876543210
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(personal_info)); //before looping

for (var key in personal_info ) {
  personal_info[key] = null;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(personal_info));//after looping and setting value to 'null'
```

Comment: Combining that with my code it won't work because we know javascript is synchronous

Comment: @FewFlyBy what problem you are facing now? how this object is generated? are you using any/more api calls to generate it?

Comment: I'm not using any api etc..  I still get the same thing

Comment: Okay, Would you mind to share what kinf of data is stored in `personal_info`? OR You can create a fiddle and paste link

Comment: You interested if I put the project in github? Just npm install and npm run dev it after..

Comment: No problem, let's give a try

Comment: This one https://github.com/sorxrob/vue-test just npm install and npm run dev and navigate the browser to http://localhost:8080/#/employees/add-employee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136317/discussion-between-vilas-kumkar-and-fewflyby).

Answer (score 2):

Vilas example is ok. But in case you have nested properties and your obj looks like this you could try my snippet

```js
var obj = {
  a: 1 ,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    e:3,
    b: {
      d:6,
      e: ['23']
    }
  }
};

var setProps = function(flat, newVal){
   for(var i in flat){
     if((typeof flat[i] === "object") && !(flat[i] instanceof Array)){
       setProps(flat[i], newVal);
       return;
     } else {
       flat[i] = newVal;
     }
  }
}
setProps(obj, null);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple immutable oneliner:

```js
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(YOUR_OBJECT).map(([key]) => [key, null])))
```

```js
const bio = {
  name: 'john',
  age: 22,
  hobbies: ['soccer']
}
const resetBio = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(bio).map(([key]) => [key, null]))

console.log(bio)
console.log(resetBio)
```