# Changing all key value pairs in an object with a for loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I am using React and JavaScript. I am trying to take an existing object with key-value pairs and make every value of the key-value pairs equal to null.

I tried using a for loop with the in keyword. Getting each key-value pair and changing it to null, but something goes wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

```
let myObj = {name: 'Bob', lname: 'Johnson'};
for (let x in myObj) {
    myObj.x = null;
}

return myObj;
```

I want the myObj variable to get all of its key-value pairs to equal to null.
End Result:

```
myObj = {name: null, lname: null};
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385110/how-to-set-all-object-properties-to-null-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the property by its name instead of accessing the property `x` on the object.

```js
let myObj = {name: 'Bob', lname: 'Johnson'}

for (let x in myObj) {
    myObj[x] = null
}

console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: Thank you dude, this worked, now that I think about it I have used this before in my code but just couldn't think of it. Once again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember when you do

```
obj.x = 'some value'
```

You are actually trying to access a property named x on the object.

But when you do

```
obj[x] = 'some value'
```

Javascript will try to resolve the value of variable x and use that as the property name.

Now it should be clear that You could run a forEach on the keys of the object and setting every property to null.

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => myObj[key] = null)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it immutable you can simply create a new object with the same keys.

```
const NullifyValues = obj => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key] = null;
    return result;
  }, {})
}

const test = {
  cat: 1,
  dog: 2,
  bat: 3
}

const nullified = NullifyValues(test);
console.log(nullified) // Object { cat: null, dog: null, bat: null }
```

Comment: You could do `return {...result, [key]: null};` inside `reduce`.

Comment: Sure if you'd like! You could also just make it into a one liner if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Update your object to use [bracket notationn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation). This way you will use the variable `x` instead of the literal value "x"

See working example below:

```js
let myObj = {name: 'Bob', lname: 'Johnson'};

for (let x in myObj) {
    myObj[x] = null; // change from myObj.x to myObj[x]
}
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

One line with vanilla JS:

```
 Object.keys(myObj).forEach(v => myObj[v] = null)
```

Comment: Nice, this works too, but I already used someone else's answer!

Comment: this is the proper way and its up to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this succintly using `Object.keys` and `forEach`:

```js
const myObj = {name: 'Bob', lname: 'Johnson'};

Object.keys(myObj).forEach(k => myObj[k] = null);

console.log(myObj);
```